# How to extract soap body from stub client

Tags: java, soap

Am newbie to SOAP world, wanted to extract soap body from a stub client, please suggest.

Comment: I have used Axis2 in order to generate client from wsdl.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? For logging purposes?

Comment: ever heard of SOAPUI?

Comment: yes for logging, wanted to do via java code